# Visual Studio 2010 addin /Projects with GUI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I'm trying to figure out how to do a VS2010 add in with gui, (like a simple popup with a few fields and an enter button)

I found stuff on stack that says Visual Studio (2010?) projects is what I need (instead of an addin) but all the tutorials I can find are for VS2008, and dont' apply to vs2010.
Is the answer outdated? what do I use?

Can anyone tell me what technology I need to use?

We have some powershell scripts that take parameters and generate code for us, I want to click on a menu item under tools (or a tool bar button) popup and ask for the parameter values, click ok, and then run the powershell. (someone else wrote the powershell, i just want to creat a built in gui for them)

As a bonus I'd like to add resultant files to the projects, but that's down the line.

Any hint or tutorials you can point me towards would be a great boon.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a pretty good article walking through creating a vs2010 extension...  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWorkspaceReloaderAVisualStudioAddInToSaveYourOpenFilesAcrossProjectReloads.aspx

Comment: Good stuff, but the addin does not have any GUI, does it? At least I didn't see any.

Comment: If you install the VS 2010 SDK (which you need to install anyways) you will find a ton of code samples which have gui, adds menus, etc.